# HTML redirect link

Tags: html

Can anyone tell me how an HTML page will be created with 5 website names like Google, Yahoo etc. and when we click on the specified link like Google we need to redirect to Google home page?

Comment: Elaborate on your question please, and in the future I would suggest avoiding the statement "its urgent" in your query.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Sample Webpage with links</title>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="http://google.com">Google</a><br/>
   <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a><br/>
   <a href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a><br/>
   <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the anchor tag but it's not redircting to google page. It's showing page loader error.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Next time when i post a question I won't type it's urgent.